# How to find out the repeated column values from a single datatable based on condition using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

[image]

based on distinct values from Artname field, I want to get the  common LND_ISO values.

1. TestCPCN-Red - AD,AG
2. TestCPCN-Green- AD
3. TestCPCN-Blue- AD,AG

so common value is AD       [ Result is AD]

How can I achieve through LINQ.

Comment: Is this question still actual?

Answer (score 1):

Simply grouping using `GroupBy` on `Artname` and then intersect on the joined result to get the output

```
var result = data.GroupBy(
    p => p.Artname, 
    p => p.LND_ISO,
    (key, g) => new { Artname = key, LND_ISO = g.ToList() }).ToList();

var output = result[0].LND_ISO;
foreach(var item in result)
{
   output = output.Intersect(item.LND_ISO);
}
```

Comment: That's not what OP wants. He wants to find those ISO's which are in all groups

Comment: @TimSchmelter Realized that and  I have updated the answer for same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var groups = from r in rows
    group r by r.Artname
    into g
    select g;

var itemsInAllGroups = (from p in rows
    where groups.All(g => g.Any(item => item.LND_ISO == p.LND_ISO))
    select p.LND_ISO).Distinct().ToList();
```